# Angular 5 - Returning data from subscribe not working, returns string "true" instead of expected JSON object

Tags: angular, promise, observable, subscribe

I have an AuthService which has a function login which subscribes to http request and returns a promise which resolves to JSON data that I get from the http request. 
Calling this function from a component, I am calling .then() to console.log() the data received, but, unexpectedly, the data returns string "true" and nothing else.

Here are the relevant snippets from my code -

auth.service.ts :

```
loginAPI(data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.apiService.apiLogin(data).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
        resolve(data);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
        reject();
      }
    )
  });
}
```

login.component.ts :

```
login() {
  if (this.loginForm.valid) {
    this.authService.login(this.loginForm.value).then(data => {
      if (data =! null) {
        console.log("Session starting with data: "+data);
        this.sessionService.start(data);
      }
    });
  } else {
    // do something
  }    
}
```

Now, here in the login.component.ts, in function login(), I am printing the data but it just prints "Session starting with data true" where it should print the JSON data.

In function loginAPI(data), the data is received from an HTTP call from another service called apiService where the http post is performed.

Whereas, the console.log(data) from the loginAPI(data) function is printing the JSON response correctly. It means data is receiving correctly from

So, where am I going wrong???

Comment: Your `if` is the wrong way round. try `if (data != null)`

Comment: `data =! null` => `data = !null` => `data = !false` = > `data = true`

Comment: Ohh f&%k!!! Such a silly mistake. Thank you for the simple explaination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your if statement in LoginComponent. You make an affectation instead of a comparison.

replace `if (data =! null) {` by `if (data != null) {` in the loginComponent.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try replacing ' if (data =! null)' with '**if(data)**'.
2. If you still get success, just have a look at the data you are sending from the backend. You might be sending a flag instead of the data itself.